# What is the meaning of どうじゃい

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the definition of this phrase.

Comment: Do you understand どう[だい](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_dai_-090)?

Comment: It means "What do you think?" or "How about that?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you heard this in anime? or it might be dialect as well

It means "How about xxx ?"

proper japanese would be "どうだい"　or even more proper "どうですか？"

Answer (score 3):

this is more informal way, 'How about this?'

More formal saying, "これで、どうですか？"